# Set Access-Control-Allow-Origin without server side scripting

Tags: html, tomcat, cors

I am trying to set the HTTP header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" but all of the examples that I find involve servlets or PHP or assume that there is server-side scripting available. Is it possible to set this in a plain old HTML file? I have tried this but I cannot verify that it is working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd" >
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" content="*"/>
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [url-rewrite](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/). You will have to configure the Filter in your web application, but you won't have to write any Java code to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I am trying to do this from within the page. I get the suspicion that it is too late once I get to the page, the http headers have already been sent. I probably can't influence the http headers from inside my html header.

Comment: Unfortunately, `<meta http-equiv` is mostly a joke. The browser would ignore any of those values is there were any response headers being returned by the server. You can use a custom `Filter` but there's no benefit to doing that over url-rewrite unless you just want to practice your Java skills.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer (it is the only one) with the actual answer appearing to be that it is in fact not possible.

Comment: Well, the server has to serve this header and it's not going to do it without being asked. It does not require scripting *per se*, but it does require configuration of some kind. Apache httpd's `mod_headers` can do it, and so can `url-rewrite` configured in Tomcat. But it's not scripting... it's configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old, but the correct way of setting a content security policy without server-side is using the meta tag Content-Security-Policy

For example:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'">
```

or in your case / example, allowing everything:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="*">
```

Read more: https://content-security-policy.com/examples/meta/